# Ejecutar un bloque dependiendo de timestamps en Ruby

Tags: ruby

Quiero que se ejecute un bloque de código, con la siguiente condición:

En una variable tengo guardado un timestamp, ej. `@tiempo` fecha: 2018-06-11 18:04:25 -0500, y el tiempo actual es `# => 2018-06-13 18:04:25 -0500`

Si la diferencia entre la variable `@tiempo` y el tiempo actual es de 2 días, ejecuta el siguiente código, si no, ejecuta otro bloque de código, algo así:

```
if @tiempo.days_ago(2).from.now
  # ejecutar un bloque de código
else
  # otro código
end
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes restar las fechas y comparar contra el resultado (el cual será en segundos); por ejemplo:

```
if Time.now - @tiempo >= 172_800
  # ejecutar un bloque de código
else
  # otro código
end
```

- *`172_800` es el total de segundos en dos días (60 segundos * 60 minutos * 24 horas * 2 días).*

Comment: Gracias @Gerry funciono perfecto!